# aws ec2 ubuntu setting up sftp with username/password not able to connect

Tags: amazon-ec2, vsftpd

I have installed and setup sftp on an Ubuntu LAMP server. however my issue is in putty if I run the command

```
sftp -vvv ftpuser@mydomain.com
```

I am able to connect. However if I try to connect in filezilla 
I get an error that states

```
Error:  Server unexpectedly closed network connection
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I am using my username and my password I created. Also I know the needed port is open because I am using the same ec2 security group as I am using for another ec2 which I have sftp working just fine for?

When I look in /etc/var/log I do not have any security log so not sure where to look to troubleshoot the issue of being able to sftp via putty command line but not via filezilla?

I have looked in my sshd_config file and I have 
PasswordAuthentication yes which of course is uncommented

Comment: When I connect to my Amazon Linux server by ssh or ftp I have to use a certificate. Is Ubuntu configured differently, is just a password enough?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check the sshd_config in the server, in AWS password auth is usually disable.
Look for the option PasswordAuthentication and check the status.